# How do you set a process up so it executes after another process?

Tags: php, mysql, linux

I have a php video uploader script and at the end it initiates an ffmpeg script for the conversion of the uploaded file. It then inserts the video info into a mysql database and in the status field, a value of 0 since the file is being processed.

I was thinking that along with the linux ffmpeg command I could put a delayed process that executes a php file so that after the file is converted and the ffmpeg process is complete it executes the php file and that file has an update statement and can update the video entry in the mysql database under status to 1. To do that though I need to somehow pass the video id into the terminal so it can pass it to the php file...Anyone know how to do this?

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO video (id, uploader, video_id, status) VALUES(?,?,?,?)';
$stmt3 =$conn->prepare($sql);
$result=$stmt3->execute(array($id,$username,$video_id,0));

$command = shell_exec('/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i /home/g/Desktop/'.$id2.' -acodec libfaac -aq 100 -vcodec libx264 -preset slow -crf 22 -threads 0 /home/g/Desktop/'.$id2.'.flv');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$command = shell_exec('/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i /home/g/Desktop/'.$id2.'' .
    '-acodec libfaac -aq 100 -vcodec libx264 -preset slow -crf 22 -threads 0' .
    '/home/g/Desktop/'.$id2.'.flv && /usr/bin/php /home/g/bin/update_db.php ' . $id2);
```

It says to execute `'/usr/bin/php /home/g/bin/update_db.php ' . $id2` if the `ffmpeg(1)` command succeeds. (It might fail.)

To try this at the shell: `true && echo hi` and `false && echo hi`.

Comment: so then is $id2 being posted or get to update_db.php? what do you refer to it as in the file?

Comment: @Scarface, it would probably be [`$argv[1]` or `$argv[2]`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php). (I don't know if `$argv[0]` would be the PHP interpreter `/usr/bin/php` or if `$argv[0]` would be the PHP script `/home/g/bin/update_db.php`. But some small tests would show. :)